# scala AST Select node can't find members inherited from parent

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect

I'm writing a macro called `assign` whose job is to assign values from members of one instance to another with a particular prefix added to the name of the member. For example, I have an instance with members named `my_prefix_data, my_prefix_rden, ...` and I want to assign values to these members from another instance with corresponding members named `data, rden, ...`. I've made a prototype version of the macro that just handles the `my_prefix_data <- data` assignment. The assignments are to be made using a special method `:=`, because this macro is ultimately going to be applied to [Chisel](https://www.chisel-lang.org/) code.

Unfortunately, it's not working. The macro implementation looks like this

```scala
package my_macros

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox


object Macro {
  def assign(foo: Any, prefix: String, bundle: Any): Unit = macro Impl.assign
}

class Impl(val c: blackbox.Context) {
  def assign(
    foo: c.Tree, // Foo
    prefix: c.Tree, // string
    bundle: c.Tree // bundle
  ): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val Literal(Constant(p: String)) = prefix
    Apply(
      Select(
        Select(
          foo,
          TermName(s"${p}_data")
        ),
        TermName(":=")
      ),
      List(
        Select(
          bundle,
          TermName("data")
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

I have a failing test case set up like this

```scala
package my_macros

import org.scalatest._

class MacroSpec extends FlatSpec {
  behavior of "Macro"
  it should "access parent methods" in {
    class Data(initial: Int) {
      var value: Int = initial
      def :=(other: Data): Unit = {
        value += other.value
      }
    }

    class UInt(initial: Int) extends Data(initial) {}

    class FooBundle {
      val my_prefix_data = new UInt(1)
    }

    class BarBundle {
      val data = new UInt(2)
    }

    val foo = new FooBundle
    val bar = new BarBundle

    Macro.assign(foo, "my_prefix", bar)

    assert(foo.my_prefix_data.value == bar.data.value)
  }
}
```

It's failing with error

```
[error] value := is not a member of UInt
[error]   Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.
[error]     Macro.assign(foo, "my_prefix", bar)
[error]                 ^
```

Why does the `Select` AST node fail to find the inherited `:=` from `UInt`'s parent class `Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is irrelevant. For

```
class UInt(initial: Int) {
  var value: Int = initial
  def :=(other: UInt): Unit = {
    value += other.value
  }
}
```

behavior is the same.

Replace `TermName(":=")` with `TermName("$colon$eq")` or with `TermName(":=").encodedName` or replace manually built tree

```
val Literal(Constant(p: String)) = prefix
Apply(
  Select(
    Select(
      foo,
      TermName(s"${p}_data")
    ),
    TermName(":=")
  ),
  List(
    Select(
      bundle,
      TermName("data")
    )
  )
)
```

with quasiquote

```
val q"${p: String}" = prefix
val pdata = TermName(s"${p}_data")
q"$foo.$pdata.:=($bundle.data)"
```

Then the code compiles.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! As a small follow-up, can you point me to where the list of symbols that needed to be converted to the $ equivalent is documented? I can't seem to find anything like it in the api docs for scala-reflect

Comment: @alcorn Because it's not part of API. It's internal convention (with dollar signs). Part of API is `.encodedName`, `.decodedName`. Look at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/reflect/NameTransformer.scala