# Creating pseudo-assignement using Scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm trying to transform this:

```scala
@Property("test")  
private var testOpt: Option[String] = Option.empty
```

into

```scala
private var testOpt: Option[String] = Option.empty

def test: Option[String] = testOpt
def test_=(value: Option[String]) = testOpt = test
```

Using this code: https://hasteb.in/rawulipe.scala

Everything work fine except when using the `_=` suffix, getting

```
value test_= is not a member of <the class of the testOpt variable>
```

Work fine when adding this method manually. Any idea ?

Comment: If you're not adding any logging or verifying behavior, could you just use a `var test`?

Comment: The final goal is to allow to `test = "foo"` while `test` returns `Option[String]`

Comment: Connected discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/j7i709/creating_pseudoassignement_method_using_macros/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
val setter = TermName(s"${defName}_=")
```

with

```
val setter = TermName(s"${defName}_=").encodedName.toTermName
```

or

```
val setter = TermName(s"${defName}_$$eq")
```

Usage:

```
@Property("test")
private var testOpt: Option[String] = Option.empty
  
//scalac: {
//  private var testOpt: Option[String] = Option.empty;
//  def test: Option[String] = testOpt;
//  def test_$eq(value: Option[String]): Unit = testOpt = value;
//  ()
//}

test = Some("a") // compiles
```

[scala AST Select node can't find members inherited from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002619/scala-ast-select-node-cant-find-members-inherited-from-parent)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I finally found a shorter way: replacing `=` by `$eq`.

Comment: @Il_totore yeah, for this case, but generally `=` is not the only such symbol.